# Given ¬(p ∨ q), use the Fitch system to prove (¬p ∧ ¬q).

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So, I understood that in order to succeed I should prove ¬p and ¬q and then use And Introduction. 
However, I don't seem to figure out how to do this and was only able to prove       (¬p ∨ ¬q) (I'm not sure if I'm even on the right path) 
I hope somebody can help me out

Comment: Try assuming p, then get a contradiction, from which you can use the contradiction elimination rule.

Comment: Well, there's more than one proof.  Note that a proof is a particular sequence, so any change in order of steps makes a distinct proof.  For one proof assume p first, get to $\lnot$p.  For another, assume q first and get to $\lnot$q.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

> $\lnot\left(p\lor q\right)$
>
> > $p\quad$ hyp.
> >
> > $p\lor q$
> >
> > $\left(p\lor q\right)\land\left(\lnot\left(p\lor q\right)\right)$
>
> $\lnot p$
>
> > $q\quad$ hyp.
> >
> > $p\lor q$
> >
> > $\left(p\lor q\right)\land\left(\lnot\left(p\lor q\right)\right)$
>
> $\lnot q$
>
> $\lnot p\land\lnot q$

You just need to fill in the justification for each line.

Answer (score 0):

## proof

```
GOAL:     ~p  &  ~q                    conclusion
```

so we need to derive `~p` and we also need to derive `~q`

we are given no atomic expressions in the premise set, therefore *reductio ad absurdum* is the only way forward.

> Assume the negation of what you want to prove and show that this negation results in a contradiction

In this case we want to prove `~p` so we start by assuming `p` and then showing that `p` entails a contradiction.

```
1.     ~(p|q)                    premise
2.         p                     assumption 
3.         ~(p|q)                reiteration                 1
4.     p => ~(p|q)               implication introduction    2-3
5.         p                     assumption                  
6.         p|q                   or introduction             6
7.     p =>  (p|q)               implication introduction    5-6
```

Thus we have a contradiction. How can `p` imply both `~(p|q)` and `(p|q)`?
We can thus conclude that `~p` is the case.

```
8.     ~p                         negation introduction      4,7
```

We need to repeat this process to produce `~q`

```
9.          q                     assumption 
10.         ~(p|q)                reiteration                 1
11.     q => ~(p|q)               implication introduction    10-11
12.         q                     assumption                  
13.         p|q                   or introduction             13
14.     q =>  (p|q)               implication introduction    13-14
15.     ~q                        negation introduction       12,15
```

Now it is easy to derive our conclusion

```
16.     ~p & ~q                   and introduction            8, 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to prove with Fitch [printscreen  in fitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raeDA.png)
Note: lines without numbers mean a subproof

1. ¬(R v S)

   R

   R v S         :V Intro 2

   ⊥             :⊥Intro 1,3

   5. ¬R           :¬ Intro 2-5

      S

      R V S       :v Intro 6

      ⊥           :⊥Intro 7,1
   6. ¬S          :¬ Intro 6-7

   10.¬R∧¬S      : ∧ Intro 5,9